# global variables between page lifecycle is not updated when parse from JSON

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, page-lifecycle

In JqueryMobile page i declared global variables, as arrays in Script of HTML page

```
 <script src="map.js"></script>

 <script>
 var longitude= new Array();
 var latitude= new Array();
 var time=new Array();
 var date=new Array();
 </script> 
 </head>
 <body>
 <div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" id="page-map">
        <h3>
           Route Map
        </h3>
    </div>        

    <div data-role="content" id="map-content">
            <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </div><!-- /content -->
  </div>
  </body>
```

and external map.js file contains

```
 $(document).delegate("#home", "pagebeforecreate", function(){  
  console.log("pagebeforecreate :");
var jqxhr = $.getJSON("file:///android_asset/www/da.json", function(data) {

      $.each(data, function(i,ele)
        {
            longitude.push(ele.longitude);
        latitude.push(ele.latitude);
        time.push(ele.time);
        date.push(ele.date); 

        }); 
    }).done(function() { console.log( "second success" ); })
    .fail(function() { console.log( "error" ); alert("parsing error");})
    .always(function() { console.log( "complete" ); });

jqxhr.complete(function(){ console.log("second complete"); 
 console.log("longitude"+longitude);
});

  });
  $(document).delegate("#home", "pageinit", function(){  
console.log("pageinit :"+longitude.length+" and "+latitude.length);
    var center= new google.maps.LatLng(latitude[0],longitude[0]);
   var myOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: center,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }     
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
         var polylineCoordinates=new Aaary();
           for(var i=0;i<longitude.length;i++)
            {
             polylineCoordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(latitude[i],longitude[i]));
            }

  var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: polylineCoordinates,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      editable: true
  });

  polyline.setMap(map); 

  }); 
  $(document).delegate("#home", "pagebeforeshow", function(){  
//longitude
console.log("pagebeforeshow :"+lon.length+" and "+lat.length);
   });
```

When i run this code the lifecycle pattern pagebeforecreate -> pageinit -> pagebeforeshow ->pageshow  has to be executed.
 For me as same but what happend is, what ever code(ajax) is in Pagebeforecreate is not complets its executing went to next and accessing pageinit block, Hence which ever data i am parsing from json file is pushed to global variables latitude and longitude are taken as null in pageinit.
  so, what is the correct way?

```
see my logcat file

     I/Web Console(4201): pagebeforecreate : at file:///android_asset/www/parse.js:2
     I/Web Console(4201): pageinit :0 and 0 at file:///android_asset/www/parse.js:23
     I/Web Console(4201): pagebeforeshow :0 and 0 at file:///android_asset/www/parse.js:27
     I/Web Console(4201): pageshow: 0 and 0 at file:///android_asset/www/parse.js:73
     I/Web Console(4201): second success at file:///android_asset/www/parse.js:13
     I/Web Console(4201): complete at file:///android_asset/www/parse.js:15
     I/Web Console(4201): second complete at file:///android_asset/www/parse.js:17
     I/Web Console(4201): longitude77.652633,77.651281,77.6492,77.647741,77.647312,77.647011,77.646861,77.646689,77.645016,77.643578,77.642097,77.640831,77.640917 at file:///android_asset/www/parse.js:18
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your global variables in map.js right at the beginning.

Also move your entire logic from pagebeforecreate to pagebeforeshow or pageshow.

Also note page init will fire only once, so if you want values every time in your page, have the logic in pagebeforeshow or pageshow.